# Correct way to retrieve a single object from Realm database

Tags: database, swift, realm

I am absolutely loving Realm (0.92) in combination with Swift but have a question about reading an object from the database. My goal is to retrieve a single object with a known, unique ID (which also happens to be the primary key.

All the documentation appears to be oriented around queries for multiple objects which are then filtered. In this case I know the object ID and, since it is known to be unique, would like to retrieve it directly.

My current approach is as follows:

```
Realm().objects(Book).filter("id == %@", prevBook.nextID).first
```

This seems heavy-handed. Documentation from prior versions suggest that there is a more direct way but I can't seem to locate it in the documentation.

The problem with my current approach is that it is crashing with an exception on the following function:

```
public func filter(predicateFormat: String, _ args: CVarArgType...) -> Results<T>
```

The exception is mysteriously reported as:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xedf)

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Anticipating one line of questioning: I have confirmed that replacing prevBook.nextID with a known, good ID does not solve the problem

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[object(ofType:forPrimaryKey:)](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm6objectu0_RxCS_6ObjectrFT6ofTypeMx13forPrimaryKeyq__GSqx_) is what you're looking for: `Realm().object(ofType: Book.self, forPrimaryKey: prevBook.nextId)`. There's no simpler way than `filter().first` if you need to search for the object by something other than the primary key.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I had to call it with objectForPrimaryKey(Book.self, key: prevBook.nextID)

Comment: For anyone looking for this still, know that the method has been updated to `object(ofType:forPrimaryKey:)`. The above example is now `Realm().object(ofType: Book.self, forPrimaryKey: prevBook.nextId)`